# XElement.SetElementValue with xml string paramter and preserve xml wrapping

Tags: c#

Is that possible to set an element value by already serialized XML string?

```
 var obj = new XElement("object");
 obj.SetElementValue("InnerXml", "<testXml>Test_data</testXml>");
```

Result is:

```
<object>
    <InnerXml>&lt;testXml &gt;Test_data &lt;/testXml&gt;</InnerXml>
</object>
```

But I would like to get this:

```
<object>
    <InnerXml><TestXml>Test_data</TestXml></InnerXml>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create each element at once and add them to the root element. if you are loading the string dynamically you can  use [`XElement.Parse Method (String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

something like this

```
        var obj = new XElement("object");
        //obj.SetElementValue("InnerXml", "<testXml>Test_data</testXml>");
        XElement elt = new XElement("InnerXml");
        obj.Add(elt);
        XElement elt2 = XElement.Parse("<testXml>Test_data</testXml>");  
        elt.Add(elt2);
```

Comment: That's not possible. The string is not static. So I can't hardcode it. This testxml is just an example.

Comment: what you  mean by not static

Comment: It can be anything another xml.

Comment: that sounds better, I'll try it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45818/discussion-between-speti43-and-k-b)

Comment: I'm at work  and chat is blocked by the admin sorry :)